# 2D Taylor expansion of F(x,y) where F(x,y) is harmonic (a solution of Laplace equation)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, harmonic-functions

I would like to know if, given F(x,y) a real function of 2 variables that obeys  $\nabla^{2} \left(F \left( x,y \right)\right) = 0$ , is it true that F(x,y) always equals its Taylor expansion within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series? Or are there more conditions that are required?

Comment: If you are imposing boundary conditions within the radius of convergence, the Taylor expansion will fail at the boundary, but the Taylor expansion will still be valid in the interior.

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic functions are analytic, so the answer is yes.